# Delete zero values for Lat-Long columns on a batch of files

Tags: r, batch

I have a script to delete 0 values from a shapefile attribute table which I have converted into a csv.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Florian/Documents/R/Evan")
data = read.csv("AF_486_2005_culled_geo_Events_shp.csv", sep=",") #read data as matrix (arrays) 

nrow(data) # test how many rows
Not0 <- which(data$LATITUDE == 0) #output which rows = 0
data <- data[-Not0,] # new data = old data with rows != 0
nrow(data) # test how many rows
write.csv(data, file = "AF_486_2005_culled_geo_Events_shp_-00.csv") #output new file
```

Only problem is I have hundreds of these csv files. How do I apply this script on all of them? I realize this is a novice question, and from my research I know that functions like 'lapply' exist, I am just inept at using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. It wasn't elegant or probably the perfect method, but it worked perfectly for my needs:

```
setwd("C:/Users/evan/Desktop/mydir")
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

for(x in 1:length(temp)) {
data=read.csv(temp[x])
nrow(data) # test how many rows
Not0 <- which(data$LATITUDE == 0) #output which rows = 0
data <- data[-Not0,] # new data = old data with rows != 0
nrow(data) # test how many rows
write.csv(data, file = temp[x]) #output new file
}
```

Comment: Don't use existing R commands as object names (eg., data) as it will cause unexpected results. Without more reporting (ie., file name), the use of nrow is useless in a for loop because, without context, it will print useless numbers. The use of "csv$" was intentional, using a common expression, and you should understand why before changing to a wildcard. It is also good to get in the habit of concise coding. Do not create objects if they are not needed, which means understanding nesting. Aside from the alternative I provided, you could also use: d <- d[-which(d$LATITUDE == 0),]

Answer (score 3):

If you want a relevant answer, you really need to provide a data structure (eg., is there a directory hierarchic or is everything in a single directory) and your workflow (how the data was generated and what you have tried) for creating the data. Somebody may be able to catch something in the workflow that would solve your problem before it becomes an issue. If this question is related to code in [Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shapefile’ for signature ‘"NULL"’](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243313), it is very relevant that you provide some background in your workflow.

There is really no need to convert your shapefile(s) into a flat file csv format to remove zero values in a column. You can read them using readOGR and then delete zero column values. If done correctly, the entire spatial object will be subset.

This does however, raise a question; why do you have zero values in a coordinates column? If they were originally shapefiles, the coordinates are inherent in the data and could be compared to what is in the data.frame column to see if, indeed, they are missing or zero values. If they are not missing then you could populate the columns using the sp:coordinates function. Please keep in mind that you do not need coordinates in the attribute table of shapefiles or spatial class objects in R and you can have a valid feature with invalid values in an attribute column.

To directly address your question, you seem like a bit of a novice R user so, a `for` loop would be most appropriate solution here. The use of `which` returns a position index of the query but, in this case there is no need to use it. A simple index query will delete/retain rows in your data.frame in a single step.

In this example, I am coercing the data into an sp spatial class object and then writing a shapefile, with the same name as the csv file. If you want csv files as the output, just remove the line coercing the data and use write.csv to export the data.

```
s <- list.files(getwd(), "csv$")
  for(i in s) {
    si <- read.csv(i)
    si <- si[si$LATITUDE != 0,]
    sp::coordinates(si) <- ~LONGITUDE+LATITUDE #coerce to sp class
    rgdal::writeOGR(si, getwd(),  unlist(strsplit(i,"[.]"))[1], driver="ESRI Shapefile") # write shapefile
  }
```

Comment: This is probably a better method than what I ended up doing. Good to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: I think next time I'll try and read directly using readOGR as you suggest.