# An error occurred when using the terrain function in the production of Shiny dashboard

Tags: raster, r, terrain, aspect, shiny

I am new to the 'shiny' package. I just try to produce an aspect map from the existing DEM data using the Shiny dashboard for training purposes. However, I faced the below warning in R and error in Shiny dashboard.

`Warning: Error in h: error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘terrain’ for signature ‘"NULL"’`

`Error:error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘terrain’ for signature ‘"character"’`

I realized situations where similar errors were encountered but I didn't find the exact reason and didn't solve this issue.

Similar error - I: [What does this mean: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘A’ for signature ‘“B”’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943201/what-does-this-mean-unable-to-find-an-inherited-method-for-function-a-for-sig)

Similar error - II: [Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shapefile’ for signature ‘"NULL"’](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243313/error-in-function-classes-fdef-mtable-unable-to-find-an-inherited-method)

Here is my simple code:

```
library(shiny)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Header1"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('DEM', 'Choose DEM', multiple=FALSE, accept='asc'),
    
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("aspect")
  )
)))


server = shinyServer(function(input,output){
  
  inFile <- reactive({
    raster::terrain(input$DEM$datapath, opt = 'aspect')
  })
  
  output$aspect<-renderPlot(
    {
      plot(inFile())
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
raster::terrain(input$DEM$datapath, opt = 'aspect')
```

looks like you are calling `terrain` on the *file path* - you need to read it into a raster first. Perhaps:

```
raster::terrain(raster::raster(input$DEM$datapath), opt = 'aspect')
```

which doesn't remove the first error, which is because the field is empty. Once you upload a DEM you will get a plot:

[image]

you should probably put a test for an empty field before reading it - you are going to have to trap all sorts of other failure modes anyway, like people uploading non-DEM GDAL files...

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error arose. Thanks again.

Comment: You'll get the first error the first time because the field is empty so the uploaded file path is empty so there's no data to map. Once you've uploaded a DEM it *will* work. Put a test for a blank filename and that will stop the initial error.

Comment: It works, thank you.